# Catel 4.0: IMessageService get dialog result synchronously

Tags: c#, asynchronous, dialog, catel

How is it possible to display a dialog with IMessageService in Catel 4.0 and get it's result immediately (not asynchronously)?

Previously it was possible like this:

```
var messageService = ServiceLocator.ResolveType<IMessageService>();
var result = messageService.Show("<Message>", "<Header>", MessageButton.YesNo, MessageImage.Question);
if (result != MessageResult.Yes) 
    return;
```

Now in Catel 4.0 the documentation says:
"The use of await or Task.ContinueWith to await the result is now necessary."

I'm not that familiar with async programming and tried a lot, but in the end I couldn't get the method to wait for the actual dialog result.

I did something like this:

```
private async Task<bool> Close()
    {
        var saveChanges = false;

        var resolver = ServiceLocator.Default.GetDependencyResolver();
        var messageService = resolver.Resolve<IMessageService>();

        var result = await messageService.Show("<Text>", "<Header>", MessageButton.YesNo, MessageImage.Question);

        if (result == MessageResult.Yes)
            saveChanges = true;

        return saveChanges;
    }
```

Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong and/or provide an example how to wait and get the result synchronously?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`await` will pause the method, but not the thread. I have an [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) on my blog that you may find helpful.

```
var result = await messageService.ShowAsync("<Text>", "<Header>", MessageButton.YesNo, MessageImage.Question);
if (result == MessageResult.Yes)
    saveChanges = true;
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, that is a nice introduction and I certainly feel a bit smarter now ;). I updated my 'Close' method, to be able to await its result, but therefore I again have to declare the calling method async, which is not what I want. At some point I do want to wait, which seems not to be working.

Comment: `async` will "grow" through the code base. This is both natural and correct. Is there some reason why you don't want this?

Comment: I'll try to explain. I have a nested layout (parent tab with child tabs). When I close the parent, I first check if there are unsaved changes in any child. If true, I want to open a MessageBox and ask the user if he wants to save the changes. The method handling the parent tab close, opens the MessageBox, but because of the async call, it immediately continues and closes the parent tab. The MessageBox then is displayed 'out of context'. That's why I want to wait for the result. Hope this is comprehensible :)

Comment: @youknowwho: What you want to do is intercept (and cancel) the user's actual "close request", asynchronously display the `MessageBox` as a modal dialog, and then do the *actual* close when the `await` completes.

Comment: Ok that sounds like the way to go, will need some changes, but yeah, thanks ;)